# Making One-Side of One-To-Many Relationship in C# MongoDB know about the Many-Side

Tags: c#, mongodb, mapping, one-to-many, bson

All:

In our application, there is a Log Model class, and a LogEvent Model Class.
Log Model Class ( One-To-Many Relationship ) LogEvent Model Class.

Here is the Log Model Class ( the one side )

```
    public class ELLCsLog : ELLCsInterfaceLog
    {

         public Object Id { get; set; }
         public int UserID { get; set; }

         public DateTime DateTimeOfInterest { get; set; }
         public String DutyCycleCode { get; set; }
         public IList<Object> logEventsIdList { get; set; }
    } // end of public class ELLCsLog
```

Here is the LogEvent Model Class ( the Many-side )

```
public class ELLCsLogEvent : ELLCsInterfaceLogEvent
{
    public Object Id { get; set; }
    public Object UmbrellaLogId { get; set; }
    public Double StartTime { get; set; }
    public Double EndTime { get; set; }
    public Double Duration { get; set; }
    public int isSubmitted { get; set; }
    public int isFrozen { get; set; }
    public String Remarks { get; set; }
    public String Location { get; set; }
    public String StatusCode { get; set; }
}
```

In my code, I'm creating BsonDocument versions of my object before inserting them into MongoDB database.

1-)Given an UmbrellaLogId which represents the parent LogId, the code below inserts a LogEvent instance into the MongoDB database.

2-)The next step involves retrieving the very same LogEvent instance that I just inserted so that I can get the LogEvent's Id which is generated by MongoDB. ( I know it's inefficient, but I'm trying to get the code to work for now )

3-)I also retrieve the parent Log ( i.e the Log with the UmbrellaLogId ) so that I can add the LogEvent's Id to the IList logEventsIdList collection.

4-) ?Here is where I'm really lost, I don't know how to add the LogEvent's Id to the IList logEventsIdList? Do I have to use a BsonDocument? How do we go about doing it?

```
               MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId  UmbrellaLogIdAsObjectId = (ObjectId)UmbrellaLogId;
                BsonDocument logEventBsonDoc = new BsonDocument { 
                                         {"UmbrellaLogId",    (BsonValue)UmbrellaLogIdAsObjectId}
                                        , {"StartTime", StartTime}
                                        , {"EndTime", EndTime}
                                        , {"Duration", Duration}
                                        , { "isSubmitted", isSubmitted}
                                        , { "isFrozen", isFrozen}
                                        , { "Remarks", Remarks }
                                        , { "Location", Location}
                                        , { "StatusCode", StatusCode }
                                     }; // end of new BsonDocument
                objUtility = new Utility();
                objUtility.Insert(logEventBsonDoc,     "FMS_TM_MST_LogEvents");

                string[] arrFields = {"Id",
                                         "UmbrellaLogId", 
                                           "StartTime", 
                                               "EndTime",
                                                 "Duration",
                                                   "isSubmitted",
                                                     "isFrozen",
                                                      "Remarks",
                                                        "Location",
                                                         "StatusCode" };
                IMongoQuery query = Query.EQ("UmbrellaLogId",    (BsonValue)UmbrellaLogIdAsObjectId);
                aLogEvent = DBConnection.database.GetCollection<ELLCsLogEvent>("FMS_TM_MST_LogEvents")
                                          .Find(query).SetFields(arrFields).ToList<ELLCsInterfaceLogEvent>().FirstOrDefault();

               IMongoQuery queryForLogOfInterest = Query.EQ("Id", (BsonValue)UmbrellaLogIdAsObjectId);
              ELLCsInterfaceLog aLog = DBConnection.database.GetCollection<ELLCsLog>("FMS_TM_MST_Logs")
                                                    .Find(queryForLogOfInterest).SetFields(arrFields).ToList<ELLCsInterfaceLog>().FirstOrDefault();
```

?Here is where I'm really lost, I don't know how to add the LogEvent's Id to the IList logEventsIdList? Do I have to use a BsonDocument? How do we go about doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All:

Here is the code that will make the One-side Entity aware of the Many-Side Entities:

```
          DBConnection.database.GetCollection<Log>("Logs").Update(
                                     Query<Log>.EQ(l => l.Id, UmbrellaLogIdAsObjectId),
                                     Update<Log>.Push(l => l.logEventsIdList, aLogEvent.Id),
                                                         new MongoUpdateOptions
                                                         {
                                                             WriteConcern = WriteConcern.Acknowledged
                                                         });
```